# How to configure Comodo SSL on WSO2

Tags: wso2, ssl-certificate, wso2-cloud, wso2-identity-server

I have a single node configuration of WSO2 APIM and IS and its domain also, like https://wso2.example.com:9444/publisher and https://wso2.example.com:9444/carbon respectively...

I have purchased SSL certificate from COMODO for my domain "wso2.example.com".

Now, how can I add SSL certificate for these domains? Note: there is no web server. it's a wso2 APIM and Identity server.

Could you please share your answers here. This is my CA files: AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt, wso2.example.com.crt,COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt,COMODORSADomainValidationSecure

I followed these steps:

I have created a directory named as "cert" under /home/ec2-user/cert

And I have generated CSR and submit to Comodo.

Now, I got my certificate files from Comodo.
This is my CA files: AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt, wso2.example.com.crt,COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt,COMODORSADomainValidationSecure

Have uploaded the files to /home/ec2-user/cert and run following command.

```
1.keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias ExternalCARoot -file 
    AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt -keystore newkeystore.jks -storepass mypassword
2.keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias TrustCA -file COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt 
   -keystore newkeystore.jks -storepass mypassword
3.keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias SecureServerCA -file 
   COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt -keystore newkeystore.jks - 
    storepass mypassword
```

finally, copy all files from /home/ec2-user/cert to /repository/resources/security/
And restarted the server...(include sh wso2server.sh)
now url not loading......Please help me...

Comment: Are you getting any errors in wso2carbon.log? What did you mean by "url not loading"?

Answer (score 1):

After importing the certificates you have to configure the product to use the new keystore. There is a nice tutorial [Setting up WSO2 with a valid certificate](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/setting-up-wso2-with-a-valid-certificate) that describe the whole process of setting up WSO2 products with a certificate.

Comment: How to generate the private key (private.key) in wso2 server?